# I am looking for a way to implement Azure services as an OAuth Client to our local OAuth server

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-web-app-service, saml-2.0

I am trying to configure Azure as an OAuth2.0 client so I can use our OAuth server to authenticate users there.

There appears to be SAML2.0 support, and this would be a secondary objective if that is possible in place of OAuth.

Many thanks!
Kyle

Comment: What did you mean that configure Azure as an Oauth 2.0 client? Were you developing an web app with integrate your own OAuth server and you want deploy it to Azure? Which step block you?

Comment: Hi Fei Xue,

Sorry for the late reply, I had forgotten I asked, and came across this by chance today.

That is the step that stops me, I am not sure how to configure Azure such that I can use an OAuth server to authenticate my user accounts with the service.